# Git Rebasing 2 branches order

Tags: git, rebase

I have 2 branches

```
myBranch

devBranch
```

if I want to add commits from the devBranch ontop of myBranch using rebase, would that just be

```
git checkout myBranch

git rebase devBranch
```

I know if I used git merge, it would merge devBranch to myBranch, I'm just wondering if this would also apply for rebase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `git merge` and `git rebase` both of these commands are designed to integrate changes from one branch into another branch—they just do it in very different ways.

git merge create a merge commits on top of your `myBranch` to bring `devBranhc` changes while `git rebase` moves the entire `myBranch` to begin on the tip of the `devBranch`, effectively incorporating all of the new commits in `devBranhc`.

Example:

Assume Initial branch history is like this:

[image]

**git merge** :  `git merge devBranch`

[image]

**git rebase** : `git rebase devBranch`
[image]

Answer (score 1):

It would.

You have 3 options (as far as i know) to integrate git branches:

- `git merge --no-ff` always creates a merge commit, preserve branch commit history
- `git merge` skip creating merge commit if possible which will not preserve branch commit history
- `git rebase` doesn't create merge commit, changes `myBranch` history, preserve `myBranch` history (technically) since it will be visible in `devBranch` when you merge it (though commit is linear, no immediate clue when `myBranch` is applied in `devBranch` commit history).

**Note**: since you rebase changes history, make sure that `myBranch` is **not shared**. You might also want to `push --force` later because of this.